# Help me identify the adapter jack

Tags: power-supply, connector, identification, adapter, cable-assemblies

just met an industrial computer which has the following power adapter jack. how to identify this jack and where to find? (actually there are lots of different jacks here and there, how to identify all!).

[image]

Comment: It's curious that the connection diagram above the jack doesn't match the type of jack that it is. Has this sytem already been hacked?

Comment: 5 AMP? That must be one beefy embedded computer.

Comment: Model Number and Brand?

Comment: @DaveTweed no haking yet :D. but yes it is awkward, i don't know why they put the label, possibly to confuse the hacker ;).

Comment: @Passerby 5A might be as wrong as the pin diagram, i don't know. It is a compact industrial cpu i can't remember the name, will let u know later

Comment: @newcomer I'm not saying it's not 5A. It can be, and most likely is. The thinclients I'm used to all aim for low wattage use, considering they are thinclients, like 2A and 1A. (My hp and neowares). 5A just makes a power adaptor harder to find/more expensive to buy.

Comment: @Passerby it says Model Number: TINO System. Website: http://savenhitech.se/. Art nr: HTS-00-0446.01. s/n: 08-11-5935

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few power supplies come with a connector which fits this jack, for example the [XP Power AML120P](http://www.xppower.com/pdfs/SF_AML120.pdf).

The jack is an example of the Kycon KPJ-4S-S, and is available from [Mouser](http://uk.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Kycon/KPJX-4S-S/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtnOp%252bbbqA0021ZcksgfQb08xFR%252bCZIuxY=)

Comment: Please correct model name from KPJ-4S... KPJX-4S...

Comment: There are several variants of the Kycon KPJX-4S connector : the KPJX-4S (unshielded = blank = naked), the KPXJ-4S-S (shielded= with metal around) and the KPJXHT-4S-S (high temp, shielded): http://www.kycon.com/2013Catalogpage/DC%20Power/KPJX.pdf . Many merchants illustrates the connectors wrongly. In a NAS, I've found what seems being the shielded variant: KPJX-4S-S that you mention.  It would be good to know when the High Temp version (HT) should be used ; I assume for special industrial applications.

Answer (score 3):

Others have identified the power connector as a Kycon 4 pin:
[image: Kycon Connector]

It's not extremely common like coaxial dc barrel jack connectors, but common enough. Provide for higher Amp rating than the smaller barrel jack connectors. As I noted, your pc uses 5 Amps at 12v. I've seen these connectors on LCD monitors, thin clients/embedded pcs and small Stereos.

While the label for the connector is shown as a typical barrel jack label (Center positive), that is not correct for this connector. Any of the four pins can be V+ or Ground, or any combination of it. My thin client used 12v on the top two, and Gnd on the bottom two pins. Some thin clients use the same connector for 5v, so you need to be sure which ever adaptor you get matches the wiring needed, or you will need to rewire it. The label makes me believe that the same case is used for a number of the manufacturer's offerings, some requiring less current, thus a barrel jack connection.

As for finding the adaptor, and identifying the other ports on that embedded pc, you will be best off googling the brand and model number of the pc. Or of the motherboard inside if it has no outward branding. Most other jacks on that pc should be standard ports, ex: USB, Parallel, Serial, VGA, DVI, PS/2, Audio, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The top-right blue connector looks like a [VGA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_connector) display connector.

The bottom-right light blue connector is a [PS/2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_connector) keyboard connector (I believe this is a standard-compliant [mini-DIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini-DIN_connector) connector).

The power connector is a non-standard variation of the mini-DIN connectors. It's a [Kycon 4-pin DC power connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_connector#Kycon).