# What is this connector called? (automotive blu-ray unit)

Tags: automotive

I have an automotive grade blu-ray unit and I'm missing a cable to connecti it to a second screen.

The cable is the blue one I'm showing in the pictures (LVDS) and it is a universal FAKRA type, however, I do not know what the connector type itself is called (4 pin, round).

Would you happen to know what these are called?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe proprietary, but it's also very similar to DIN connectors. A make/model on the player would be helpful. And are you certain it is LVDS? LVDS is normally has 20 to 36 pins, in a video context.

Comment: Such shopping questions not involving design are off-topic.

Comment: @LeonHeller Not a shopping question!, just want to know what these are called.

Comment: sounds to me like a CAN bus connector, according to this http://fx.damasgate.com/physical-layers-and-media/ there's no standard for that bus connector type.

Comment: Looks a bit like a locking version of the connectors in this Q/A : http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/58490/help-me-identify-the-adapter-jack/58494#58494

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This connector seems to be a FAKRA HSD connector. Please check these links:

-www.te.com/en/industries/industrial-commercial-transportation/infotainment-solutions/high-speed-data-connector-system-hsd.html

-http://www.rosenbergerna.com/Products/30_Automotive_Standard.html

and the catalog from the Rosenberger for this type of connectors:

-http://www.rosenbergerna.com/Products/PDF/Publications/AUTO_HSD_Catalog_2010.pdf

A connector similar with the one mounted on the system is D4S20G- 400A5- D (Rosenberger catalog, page 19; the last letter is for connector type - Bordeaux).
Concerning the one mounted on wire, check the following pages.